# Cassandra Architecture use case

Tags: architecture, cassandra, database-migration

i'm new on cassandra and i had the responsibility to design a basic architecture for a use case, so i'd like to know if it's correct and have advices and points of view.

here is the context :
We need to create an application that will present some metrics[Scores, Number of visited pages..] to different kind of users[customers,admins..].

depending on the requests some metrics may required the last available data or not.

Actually we are using a third part software that stores RAW DATA into MySQL databases.

here is the solution that i think to deploy :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i38Es.png

the "RealTime DataCenter" will be filled using either Cassandra Trigger or talend jobs.

thanks in advance

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking advise on an app for managing requests from this data structure that's already constructed/being constructed or are you looking for advise on the db structure itself? Just a little clarification denoting your problem(s) and intended outcome would help myself and others assist you in finding a solution more quickly and effectively.

Comment: First of all , thanks for your quick answer, otherwise it's more about advices accodring the way wich i'm planning to use cassandra.

Comment: Okay, I think this might be a question more suited for the Database Administrators tab or Server Fault. Stackoverflow is specifically intended for coding and application troubleshooting, not so much advising on how to best use a specific application. We have a rich well of knowledge on this site but those section of this site I think would be better suited for you. Also I recommend gathering and organizing your question to show problem, intended outcome and research a little more when posted it next time, I've been chewed for much less so just trying to help out a little bit.